# How to destructure and add nested objects into exported function?

Tags: javascript

how can I export the `dynamic_template_data` object in the `sendVerificationEmail.js` module to my `sendEmail.js` module?

> `sendVerificationEmail.js`

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { sendEmail } from './sendEmail'

const TEMPLATE_ID = functions.config().sendgrid.template

export const sendVerificationEmail = functions.firestore
  .document('/temporaryUsers/{id}') // listen to any new user added to collection
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const tempUserInfo = snapshot.data()
    const { emailAddress, confirmationHash } = tempUserInfo

    return sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress,
      from: 'johndoe@acme.com',
      templateId: TEMPLATE_ID, // reference to the template we made in Sendgrid UI
      dynamic_template_data: {
        subject: 'test subject here' // <---- how to pass this to `sendEmail.js` ? See below...
      },
      subject: 'Welcome to my awesome app!',
      message: `Click this link to verify your email: https://us-central1-acme-test-api.cloudfunctions.net/confirmEmail?conf=${confirmationHash}`
    })
  })
```

> `sendEmail.js`

```
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail'
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

const API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key

sgMail.setApiKey(API_KEY)

export const sendEmail = ({ to, from, templateId, subject, message }) => {
  const mailOptions = {
    to,
    from,
    templateId, 
    <here> <-------how can I "carry over" the `dynamic_template_data` object from `sendVerificationEmail` ?
    subject,
    text: message
  }

  return sgMail.send(mailOptions, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      // Do something with the error
      console.error('error from sendEmailjs: ', error)
    } else {
      // Celebrate
      console.log('Email sent!')
    }
  })
}
```

I hope my question makes sense. I tried to do the below attempt (but obviously that didn't work...I just wanted to make the point for the question).

```
export const sendEmail = ({ to, from, templateId, dynamic_template_data.subject, subject, message }) => {
  const mailOptions = {
    to,
    from,
    templateId,
dynamic_template_data: {
subject },
    subject,
    text: message
  }
```

Comment: You want either just `({ …, dynamic_template_data, … }) => …, dynamic_template_data, …` or `({ …, dynamic_template_data: { subject }, … }) => …, dynamic_template_data: { subject }, …`. You cannot use a dot in destructuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it like so:

```
export const sendEmail = ({ to, from, templateId, dynamic_template_data, subject, message }) => {
  const mailOptions = {
    to,
    from,
    templateId,
    dynamic_template_data,
    subject,
    text: message
  }
```